# BB10 Cascades - Simulate Touch Events

Tags: qt, touch-event, blackberry-cascades

I am attempting to simulate touch events on BB10 app. My main goal is to create a touch event, for example, for pixel (100,100) and have the application handle it. This is part of an automated GUI test which will help in further deployment.

I've been messing around with this for a couple days now with no progress really. I've tried simulating touch events and then sending them using Qt send event, but that didn't seem to work. Is there any way for me to "send" an ontouch signal? Any help is greatly appreciated as I am slowly giving up.

Does anyone have any ideas at all?

Answer (score 0):

Create touch targets. For BlackBerry smartphones, create touch targets that are at least 101 x 101 pixels (7.2 mm).